# Is there no Debug.Write() method in Silverlight's System.Diagnostics?

Tags: c#, silverlight, system.diagnostics

Is there no Debug.Write() method in Silverlight's System.Diagnostics?

There's a Debug.WriteLine(), but no Debug.Write().

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Does anyone have a simple work-around?  I want to be able to do something like:

**EDIT:**

```
public static string OutAnd(this string input) {
    Debug.Write(input);
    return input;
}
```

(And yes, I'm intentionally returning the string again in case I want to use it fluently.)  I use this method in non-Silverlight contexts, and it works well for quick debugging.

Thanks!

Comment: [This isn't satisfactory?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: @Will: I don't understand what "this" refers to in your comment.  If you mean my example, then no, because there is no Debug.Write() method in Silverlight's System.Diagnostics namespace.

Comment: Hmm, I seemed to has misunderstood.  You know about WL.  I'll extension for you.

Comment: Probably has something to do with a limitation in the debugging engine for an early Silverlight or CF version.  Not that this in any way helps you solve this problem.

Comment: Hans: Yeah, I figured as much.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use the loop to append to a string builder, like so:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilderInstance=new StringBuilder();
foreach(string stringValue in stringList)
{
    stringBuilderInstance.AppendFormat("{0}, ",stringValue);
}
```

then at the end of the loop use, for instance:

```
Debug.WriteLine(stringBuilderInstance.ToString())
```

Comment: I really should have made my example more...exemplary of what I was intending to do.  I wanted to make simple extension methods on string which would allow me send them to Debug output: one with Write, and one with WriteLine.  I won't have a reference to a StringBuilder between calls to my extension method.

Answer (score 0):

In your situ, I'd use a class to hold the intermediate stuff.

```
public sealed class WriteLine
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _accumulator = new StringBuilder();

    public WriteLine OutAnd(string text)
    {
        _accumulator.Append(text);
        return this;
    }

    public void ToDebug()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(_accumulator.ToString());
    }
}
```

with the extension method

```
public static WriteLine OutAnd(this string input)
{
    var retval = new WriteLine();
    retval.OutAnd(input);
    return retval;
}
```

so, in code, you could do the following:

```
"foo".OutAnd(" bar").OutAnd(" baz").OutAnd(" are lazy variable names").ToDebug();
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I don't think this helps much.  With this I would have to maintain a reference to the WriteLine object between iterations in a loop, or between function calls.  I might as well use a StringBuilder in that case.

Comment: @Klay: Well, hell, the method doesn't exist, you can't just wish it back into the framework.  You have to do *something*.  Pick your poison and swallow :/

Comment: You know, you're right.  The quarter I threw into that fountain proved to be money ill-spent.  And I was just sharpening my tanto in preparation for ritual suicide, but I've decided to push forward thanks to your encouragement.  I'm sure I'll find another way.